# Unix permission for all files inside folder

Tags: file-permissions

How can I assure that all existing files (or future files) inside a folder in unix are always world readable ?

I am using email piping to read attachment from the email via php script and store it in some folder which will be viewable by the apache user.

Now, the email pipe is storing the attachment with rights to only user nobody and group nobody ..

How can I change it so that anyone can read the files inside that folder ?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 5):

You would need to change the umask in the environment of the user running postfix. How this is done depends on how it is started. You can most likely set it in the init script that is starting postfix.

[Controlling file permissions with umask](http://linuxzoo.net/page/sec_umask.html)

Comment: You could also set this folder sgid, but setting umask looks a cleaner way.

Comment: I was going to mention that but he said ownership was fine and seemed to be specifically concerned with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wietse in the post linked below, Postfix runs with umask 077, and it seems intentional. You might patch the code, to run with a different umask.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/postfix-users/message/254262

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file ownership of a folder and files and directories in it with

```
chown -R <owner>:<group> <myfolder>
```

Comment: folder owner ship is already set properly.. but it seems when postfix user store the attachment in that folder... it's changing the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/) a similar cron scheduler, based on file system changes.